# import dlib fails

Tags: opencv, pip

I want to use with OpenCV the library `dlib`, I installed in my virtual environment. I'm sure because with `pip list` appears:

(Thesis_env) pi@raspberrypi:~/Environments $ pip list
Package            Version

---

Babel              2.6.0
certifi            2019.3.9
chardet            3.0.4
debtcollector      1.21.0

**dlib               19.17.0**

dnspython          1.16.0
eventlet           0.24.1
fasteners          0.14.1
greenlet           0.4.15
idna               2.8
iso8601            0.1.12
monotonic          1.5
msgpack            0.6.1
netaddr            0.7.19
netifaces          0.10.9
numpy              1.16.3
opencv-python      3.4.4.19
os-win             4.2.0
oslo.concurrency   3.29.1
oslo.config        6.9.0
oslo.context       2.22.1
oslo.i18n          3.23.1
oslo.log           3.43.0
oslo.serialization 2.29.1
oslo.utils         3.41.0
pbr                5.2.0
pip                19.1.1
pyinotify          0.9.6
pyparsing          2.4.0
python-dateutil    2.8.0
pytz               2019.1
PyYAML             5.1
requests           2.22.0
rfc3986            1.3.2
setuptools         41.0.1
six                1.12.0
stevedore          1.30.1
urllib3            1.25.2
wheel              0.33.4
wrapt              1.11.1
(Thesis_env) pi@raspberrypi:~/Environments $

But now, when I run my code, appears the error:

> ImportError: No module named 'dlib'

What is wrong? This just happens with `dlib`.

Thank you

Comment: What is your command for running your code please ? the code is in a file script ? maybe try to use another version of python for calling your file (if it is a file)

Comment: Yes it's a file, I'm using python3

Comment: and you run your file with python version ?

Comment: version 3 too :(

Comment: Have you take a look [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/03/27/how-to-install-dlib/) ? `Step #4: Test out your dlib install` . Try to open your virtualenv and then do : import dlib for seeing if all work.

Comment: Omg here it's working, why in one place works but not in the other? I really don't understand

Comment: I can't understand why when I'm executing python with the shell doesn't fail but with an external file yes. Because this file is inside the folder...

Comment: I do not work with python virtual environments sorry, but I would already look for an 'env' in your python program to see environment variables...